# Set $(BuildId) to a variable

Tags: .net, tfs

I have created a build definition variable which should contain my AssemblyInfo version. I want to set $(BuildId) as a last version. How can I do it? I tried to set default value to `"1.0.0.$(BuildId)"` and to `String.Format("1.0.0.{0}", $(BuildId))` but both ways fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create custom activities to do that, check out, edit version number then check in. You can follow [Customize Team Build 2010 – Part 5: Increase AssemblyVersion](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/13/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-5-Increase-AssemblyVersion.aspx) to do it. Anyway, I recommend you read and follow all 16 parts in that list.